# Implicit differentiation with 2 unknowns

Tags: implicit-differentiation

$xy(x - 6y) = 9a^3$ , a is not 0

**The Question**

Show that there is only one point on the curve at which the tangent is parallel to the x axis, and find the coordinate of this point.

How would I go about solving this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$(*)$ $x^2y(x)-6xy(x)^2=9a^3$.

Implicit differentiation yields

$2xy(x)+x^2y'(x)-6y(x)^2-12xy'(x)y(x)=0$.

If $x_0$ is a point in the domain of $y$ with $y'(x_0)=0$, then

$2x_0y(x_0)-6y(x_0)^2=0$. Thus $y(x_0)=0$ or $y(x_0)=\frac{1}{3}x_0$

By $(*)$ we see that $y(x_0)=0$ is impossible, since $ a \ne 0$. Thus $y(x_0)=\frac{1}{3}x_0$.

Now it is your turn to show that $x_0=-3a$ and $y(x_0)=-a$.

Comment: Look's like the question is out of scope for me. I am an A Level student.

Comment: What are your problems ?

Comment: I sorta don't understand anything after the second line.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf: just explaining a bit more. $y'(x_0)$ represent the inclination of the tangent at the point $x_0$, so once the tangent is parallel to the $x$ axis then its inclination must be zero, that's why $y'(x_0)=0$. The rest is calculation.